# What does it mean [X,T]=MATRIX?

Tags: matlab

I'm starting to study [this example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/examples/character-recognition.html) but I'm not understanding the matrix operation on matlab:

Whe it does `[X,T] = prprob;` it will copy the predefined 26x35 matrix `prprog` to X and a identity matrix with less rows (26x26) to T. It works fine.

I tried the same with another matrix and got:

```
a =

     1     4
     2     5
     3     6

>> [X,T] = a
Too many output arguments.
```

What's different from my `a` matrix to this `prprog` matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This simply means that your function `prprob` returns two matrices. In other words, it has two outputs which are the two matrices you described.

When you call `[X,T] = prprob`, the right hand side term (`prprob`) will be evaluated and thus replaced by its output. Let's call `[res1,res2]` this output. Then your call will be equivalent to:

```
[X,T] = [res1,res2]
```

This call holds since the two sides share the same dimension.

However, when you call `[X,T] = a`, your right hand side term is evaluated as a single matrix and thus the two sides of your call do not share the same dimension. This is why you get the error `Too many output arguments.`

Indeed, you have one input (which is `a`) and two outputs (which are `X` and `T`).

**Note:** I saw on your profile that you develop in Java. Unlike in Java where you can only have one returned variable from a method, here in Matlab, functions can return multiple variables (in an array). This is the case here for the `prprob` function.

Oh and as the doc says in the link you provided:

> *The script **prprob** ...*

It is a function not a matrix, this might also be why you were mistaken here ;)